# How can I set the native library for a dependency using maven?

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface

I am using microsoft tfs sdk jar which requires a native library. I can set the native library using : `System.setProperty("com.microsoft.tfs.jni.native.base-directory","C:\path\");`

I am now using a maven project and the tfs sdk jar is a maven dependeny
How can I set the native library for the dependency using maven ?

Comment: What have you tried? A quick search for "maven native dependency" provides a couple of links. Didn't they contain the information you needed? Did you have a particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "Native Lib Loader" helper.

The source to one is here: https://github.com/scijava/native-lib-loader

Best via Maven/Gradle or similar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scijava/native-lib-loader/

Where you need to add the natives to the project and the required naming convention ca be found in "org.scijava.nativelib.NativeLibraryUtil"